# JWplayer with HLS video not playing on Android Devices

Tags: amazon-s3, jwplayer, http-live-streaming

I am using JWplayer to stream a video that is hosted on Amazon S3, but it won't play on Android devices.

It works fine on PC, Mac and iPhones/iPads.

I have tested with Firefox, Google Chrome and Safari.

I have no idea to what could be wrong and I would really appreciate any input.

The link to the page where the video plays is this: https://ead.starlingacademy.com.br/

Comment: Looks like it works fine.

Comment: Works for me (Chrome 61.0/Android 8.0). Using which Android version and which browser did you test with?